# Refresh banshee album art

Tags: banshee, music, multimedia, music-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Banshee re-scan for cover art?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10578/how-do-i-make-banshee-re-scan-for-cover-art)

I usually just copy `~/.config/banshee-1`, and `~/.gconf/apps/banshee-1` when i'm moving from one computer to the other, if I keep the path of the folders. I get to keep my music library intact with the playlists I have.

The problem with this method is that, the album arts doesn't carry over nicely. You'd have to play every album to get the album art to appear. Anyone knows a workaround, to maybe force banshee to reload all album art?

[image]

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65323/bulk-export-embed-album-art-in-banshee), but not quite what my issue is?

I tried `banshee --fetch-artwork`, but didn't work too well

```
kenneth@dv7:~$  banshee --fetch-artwork                                         
[Warn  11:23:38.200] DBus support could not be started. Disabling for this sessi
on. - System.Exception: Error 111: Connection refused (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Unix.UnixSocket.Connect (System.Byte[] remote_end) [0x00000] in <filen
ame unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Transports.UnixNativeTransport.OpenAbstractUnix (System.String path) [
0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Transports.UnixNativeTransport.Open (System.String path, Boolean abstr
act) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Transports.UnixTransport.Open (DBus.AddressEntry entry) [0x00000] in <
filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Transports.Transport.Create (DBus.AddressEntry entry) [0x00000] in <fi
lename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Connection.OpenPrivate (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Connection..ctor (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknow
n>:0 
  at DBus.Bus..ctor (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Exception: Unable to open the session message bus. (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName, Boo
lean init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.GrabDefaultName () [0x00000] in <filena
me unknown>:0 
[Info  11:23:38.286] Running Banshee 2.6.0: [Ubuntu 12.10 (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 
2012-10-11 06:19:37 UTC]

(Banshee:21865): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-vLxS6Riwsn: Connection refused
[Warn  11:23:38.948] Could not read GConf key core.send_anonymous_usage_data - G
Lib.GException: No D-BUS daemon running
 (in `gconf-sharp')
  at GConf.Client.Get (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.GnomeBackend.GConfConfigurationClient.TryGet[Boolean] (System.Strin
g namespace, System.String key, System.Boolean& result) [0x00000] in <filename u
nknown>:0 

(Banshee:21865): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-vLxS6Riwsn: Connection refused
[Warn  11:23:39.239] Could not read GConf key core.send_anonymous_usage_data - G
Lib.GException: No D-BUS daemon running
 (in `gconf-sharp')
  at GConf.Client.Get (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.GnomeBackend.GConfConfigurationClient.TryGet[Boolean] (System.Strin
g namespace, System.String key, System.Boolean& result) [0x00000] in <filename u
nknown>:0
```